# Book/series about a kid who goes to a school in space in some kind of exchange program

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read the first two books around 2017-2020ish.  The first book was about a kid who goes to a school in space in some kind of exchange program with different alien species. Essentially there’s a traitor among the school faculty and so the kid and his friends kind of break the rules to find and stop the traitor.

I can’t remember the title but I remember specific parts:

- the main character’s friend and potential love interest is an alien girl who resembles a purple(?) cat
- the students also get injected with nanites that enhance their capabilities and give some powers
- there is an alien that the main character meets as he’s being briefed on his trip to the space school who resembles a giraffe(?)
- the second book in the series is called “Outlaws”
- The main character had a coat that resembled the same one the main character of the Firefly series had (he and his father were fans of the show and sci-fi in general)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Was this a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13574417-alienated?

Comment: Yoicks.  There are [3 series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=exact&TERM_1=Outlaws&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) between 2017 and 2020 with a second book titled "Outlaws", but they're all fantasy series, no aliens or space school.

Answer (score 0):

Is it [Crash Landing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17658028-crash-landing) by Zac Harrison?

It has some similar aspects like going to school in outer space and alien friends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there a second book in the series with a title like "Outlaws?"  Does it match having a cat-like female character?

Comment: @DavidW - None of the sequels have the word Outlaw in the title or the blurb; https://www.goodreads.com/series/141085-hyperspace-high